# jQuery autocomplete's options are in the wrong position

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

I have a jQuery UI autocomplete field. It works, but when the suggestions pop up, the all show up in the very upper left-hand corner. I've included what I believe to be all the necessary CSS files but it's not showing up in the right place.

In fact, even when I include ALL the CSS files that come with jQuery UI, the autocomplete field shows up in the upper left-hand corner.

Comment: It sounds like a position issue; you probably have an absolute position set on the pop up, but do not have a relative position set on the containing element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was because I wasn't including jquery-ui.js. Duh.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding the jQuery UI Position script.